# Xcode - command line build

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, command-line, xcodebuild

I've been working on creating a shell script which will let me archive and extract the ipa file from my working project.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd `dirname $0`
xcodebuild -scheme appName clean archive -archivePath ./build/AppName
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist ./build/exportOptions.plist -archivePath  ./build/AppName.xcarchive -exportPath ./build/appName
```

The exportOptions.plist is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>method</key>
        <string>ad-hoc</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I will further need a way to change the Bundle identifier and the Team to the customer's. Adding `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=$com.changed.appname` to the first line of the `xcodebuild` will it change the Bundle identifier to what I need ?

i.e. `xcodebuild -scheme appName PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=$com.changed.appname clean archive -archivePath ./build/AppName`

Is this right ? What about the team ? Or should I use the exportOptions.plist for these settings ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to build the app for team A and to export your IPA for team B? This is possible due to resigning, but it's not a simple task as this isn't supported by xcodebuild out of the box... Changing the bundleID by overriding PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER like you mentioned will work if your project doesn't have hard coded bundleIDs anywhere, e.g. in the Info.plist

Comment: In the end I chose to change the bundle identifier from the shell script with: PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER="com." in the xcodebuild line of archiving. And for the team, I've changed my exportOptions.plist to add "teamID" key and the new team identifier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these commands to manipulate the project files directly. From my experience, the xcodebuild commands sometimes don't accept the parameters we pass as provisioning profiles, team ID, etc..

So the best way to guarantee it's changed the way you want is to manipulate the `xcodeproj` file

1. Changing provisioning style to manual

`sed -ie "s/ProvisioningStyle = \".*\"/ProvisioningStyle = \"Manual\"/" <project_name>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

2. Changing the code signing identity

`sed -ie "s/CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = \".*\"/CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = \"<signing_identity_name>\"/g" <project_name>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

3. Changing provisioning profile

`sed -ie "s/PROVISIONING_PROFILE = \".*\"/PROVISIONING_PROFILE = \"<provisioning_profile_udid>\"/g" <project_name>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

`sed -ie "s/PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER  = \".*\"/PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = \"<provisioning_profile_name>\”/g" <project_name>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

**Note: Please be mindful of the spaces, this method use regexs to match and replace values in your project file**